# Running Solr with SystemD: user limitations (ulimit) applied at runtime different from the configured limitations

Tags: solr, systemd

I'm trying to run solr as a SystemD service. When I start the service I get this warning then the solr server stops.

```
jun 22 16:20:07 solr_start[1488]: *** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 14972.
jun 22 16:20:07 solr_start[1488]: It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
jun 22 16:20:07 solr_start[1488]: If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
jun 22 16:20:09 solr_start[1488]: Warning: Available entropy is low. As a result, use of the UUIDField, SSL, or any other features that require
jun 22 16:20:09 solr_start[1488]: RNG might not work properly. To check for the amount of available entropy, use 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail'.
jun 22 16:20:14 solr_start[1488]: [146B blob data]
jun 22 16:20:14 solr_start[1488]: Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=1579). Happy searching!
jun 22 16:20:15 solr_stop[1680]: Sending stop command to Solr running on port 8983 ... waiting up to 180 seconds to allow Jetty process 1579 to stop gracefully.
```

I checked the code at https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/bin/solr#L1509. 
I can see that solr runs a check on ulimit -u and ulimit -n.

The strange thing is that I made sure SystemD would run the solr server with the "solr" user.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache SOLR
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
Before=multi-user.target
[Service]
User=solr
#PIDFile=/mnt/solrdata/solr-8983.pid
Environment=SOLR_INCLUDE=/opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh
ExecStart=/opt/solr/bin/solr_start
ExecStop=/opt/solr/bin/solr_stop
#Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target​
```

And this "solr" user (that I configured especially to run Solr server) can create an unlimited number of processes and open an unlimited number of files.

```
[solr@xxx ~]# ulimit -n
unlimited
[root@xxx ~]# ulimit -u
unlimited
```

When SystemD starts solr I see it uses the correct user (the "solr" user I configured). Yet I see the error above.

When I run solr directly with the "solr" user (no with SystemD), it works.

Why are the user limitations applied at runtime when I run the Solr server myself different from the ones used when run by SystemD ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Limits.conf) limit defined in `/etc/security/limit.conf` dosen't work with systemD.

To define new limit in a systemD unit file add those line in the service section:

```
LimitNOFILE=65000
LimitNPROC=65000
```

For a complete list see [the man page](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=systemd-system.conf&ampsect=5)